# %USERPROFILE% env variable for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7-x64, environment, os.path

I am writing a script in Python 2.7.

It needs to be able to go whoever the current users profile in Windows.

This is the variable and function I currently have:

```
import os
desired_paths = os.path.expanduser('HOME'\"My Documents")
```

I do have doubts that this `expanduser` will work though. I tried looking for Windows Env Variables to in Python to hopefully find a list and know what to convert it to. Either such tool doesn't exist or I am just not using the right search terms since I am still pretty new and learning.

Comment: You can access environment variables via the [`os.environ` mapping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ): `import os; print(os.environ['USERPROFILE'])`

Comment: Note that the "My Documents" junction point in the user's profile won't necessarily exist.  For example, if a non-English version of Windows is installed, or if the user's documents folder has been moved or redirected.  (You might be OK if this is for in-house use only.)

Answer (score 33):

You can access environment variables via the [`os.environ` mapping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ):

```
import os
print(os.environ['USERPROFILE'])
```

This will work in Windows.  For another OS, you'd need the appropriate environment variable.

Also, the way to concatenate strings in Python is with `+` signs, so this:

```
os.path.expanduser('HOME'\"My Documents")
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

should probably be something else.  But to concatenate *paths* you should be more careful, and probably want to use something like:

```
os.sep.join(<your path parts>)
# or
os.path.join(<your path parts>)
```

(There is a slight distinction between the two)

If you want the My Documents directory of the current user, you might try something like:

```
docs = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], "My Documents")
```

Alternatively, using expanduser:

```
docs = os.path.expanduser(os.sep.join(["~","My Documents"]))
```

Lastly, to see what environment variables are set, you can do something like:

```
print(os.environ.keys())
```

(In reference to finding a list of what environment vars are set)

Answer (score 5):

Going by [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) , using a `~` would seem more reliable than using `'HOME'`.